# Replace dots with comma in a table with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table filled with data coming from an AJAX call, and all this data (both numeric and strings) are inserted in td and tr tags as usual.
I need to replace all the dots in decimal numbers with commas, but I wouldn't like to call the method "replacewith()" in every  manually.
I thought of something like this:

```
$( document ).ready() {
   $(#"<tr>").isNumeric().replaceWith('.', ',');
}
```

so that when the page is charged jquery automatically detects the numbers in the table cells and replace their numbers with comma.

I don't even know if this idea is possible...however, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: jQuery has in fact a `isNumeric()-Function`. You could call it on the  text content of every row.

Comment: But what I would like to avoid is exactely this: put me on the context of every row...I want to write this function just once and call it at the beginning of the page containing the table

Comment: Select all `<tr>` with `$("yourTable").children("tr")` from the table and iterate trough them the $.each().

Comment: you like to replace '.' with ',' just for numeric fields? in all the tr htmls?

Comment: yes, exactely. Currently I'm trying this:    `$("ddtable").children("td").each().isNumeric().replaceWith('.',','); `                       , but it seems it doesn't work

Comment: Try this is this helpful for you if not let me know will put some extra effort for you.
        $('#ddtable tr td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).html().match(/^\s*\d[\d,\.]*\s*$/)) {
                var htmlval = $(this).html();
                htmlval = htmlval.replace('.', ',');
                $(this).replaceWith(htmlval);
            }
        });

Comment: just asking above code working for you? or need some **improvement**

Comment: uhm not yet, I didn't work

Comment: Are you getting data from server? You can loop through data. You would know which columns can have numeric fields. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to automatically detect when elements are added to the page. You could use AJAX global events to detect when an AJAX call is made and use a timer to wait until the result has been processed, but that would mean that you have to check all table cells in the page for every AJAX call, there is a delay until the cells are corrected, and it still won't cover all situation.

Calling a function manually is some extra work, but it's the most reliable and efficient way to do it.

You would call the function with the elements that you want to process. That way you don't have to look through all table cells in the entire page.

Look for the table cells rather than table rows. You should look at the nodes in the cell rather than just do a replace on anything in it, otherwise you would risk messing up parts of the code that isn't actually text. To handle nested elements you call the function recursively for any nodes that are not text nodes.

Example:

```js
function fixPeriods(elements) {
  elements.contents().each(function(i, el){
    if (el.nodeType == 3) {
      if ($.isNumeric(el.data)) {
        el.data = el.data.replace(/\./g, ',');
      }
    } else {
      fixPeriods($(el));
    }
  });
}

fixPeriods($('#Bjursta td'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="Bjursta">
  <tr><td>3.14</td><td>4.5<b>2.3</b>1.8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1.337</td><td>Not a number.</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7.65</td><td>127.0.0.1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why it's not possible detect when elements are added to the page, if there is a MutationObserver?

Comment: @Alex78191: You are right, that is an alternative. At the time it was a recently added feature, so you couldn't expect support for it.

Answer (score 5):

Try to give your table a class for behavior and then use something like this in document ready:

```
$(function() {
 $('.myTable td').each(function () {
  if($.isNumeric($(this).html())) {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('.', ','));
  }
 });
});
```

jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wtzkbm7n/

Comment: This one looks easier!

Comment: I tried this one too, but it still doesn't work. But the problem could be the entire project, that it's more complicate than the way I put it on. So, at this point, I will follow Guffa's suggestion, and 'll go for calling the function in the points I need. Thanks you all